# Win10S causes Certified W10 App to fail writing data to APPDATA

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

Our win10app was accepted earlier in Win10Store without problems, but now lately new Win10S requirements seem to cause certification/testing phase failure even while the appx package has not been changed for a year. App seem to fail certification because of app gives out a file write failure / access denied.

Our destop bridged app is simply storing data files to %appdata% folder, what would be the correct path to write user's own data files that works in both Win10S and Windows 10 Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP apps are supposed to write local data to the local app folder:

```
%localappdata%\Packages\[app-package-name]\LocalState
```

which is usually accessed through an [StorageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder) object returned by the [ApplicationData.LocalFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata) property.

```
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Get the app's local folder.
StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

// Create a new file in the current folder.
// Raise an exception if the file already exists.
string desiredName = "test.txt";
StorageFile newFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists);
```

You can use the same code in your desktop bridge app to access the local folder of your app.

Comment: Thanks I used CSIDL_APPDATA